# Android - get user phone's International Country Calling Code

Tags: android, twilio

I want to get an Android phone's `international country calling code` based on the locale of the phone.

I can get the local of the phone like this:

`Locale.getDefault().getCountry()`

But that doesn't equal to the international country calling code. For example `Locale JAPANESE = "ja"` but the international calling code for Japan is `"JA"`

I am trying to get the international calling code of the phone based on the local and not the SIM card because some phones might not have SIM cards and be data only. I want to pre-fill the country code based on the user's locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to do that. You can convert dialing code

```
<string-array name="DialingCountryCode" >
    <item>32,BE</item>
    <item>501,BZ</item>
    <item>229,BJ</item>
    <item>975,BT</item>
    <item>591,BO</item>
    <item>387,BA</item>
    <item>267,BW</item>
    <item>55,BR</item>
    <item>673,BN</item>
    <item>359,BG</item>
    <item>226,BF</item>
    <item>95,MM</item>
    <item>257,BI</item>
    <item>855,KH</item>
    <item>237,CM</item>
    <item>1,CA</item>
    <item>238,CV</item>
    <item>236,CF</item>
    <item>235,TD</item>
    <item>56,CL</item>
    <item>86,CN</item>
    <item>61,CX</item>
    <item>61,CC</item>
    <item>57,CO</item>
    <item>269,KM</item>
    <item>242,CG</item>
    <item>243,CD</item>
    <item>682,CK</item>
    <item>506,CR</item>
    <item>385,HR</item>
    <item>53,CU</item>
    <item>357,CY</item>
    <item>93,AF</item>
    <item>355,AL</item>
    <item>213,DZ</item>
    <item>376,AD</item>
    <item>244,AO</item>
    <item>672,AQ</item>
    <item>54,AR</item>
    <item>374,AM</item>
    <item>297,AW</item>
    <item>61,AU</item>
    <item>43,AT</item>
    <item>994,AZ</item>
    <item>973,BH</item>
    <item>880,BD</item>
    <item>375,BY</item>
    <item>420,CZ</item>
    <item>45,DK</item>
    <item>253,DJ</item>
    <item>670,TL</item>
    <item>593,EC</item>
    <item>20,EG</item>
    <item>503,SV</item>
    <item>240,GQ</item>
    <item>358,FI</item>
    <item>33,FR</item>
    <item>291,ER</item>
    <item>372,EE</item>
    <item>251,ET</item>
    <item>500,FK</item>
    <item>298,FO</item>
    <item>679,FJ</item>
    <item>689,PF</item>
    <item>241,GA</item>
    <item>220,GM</item>
    <item>995,GE</item>
    <item>49,DE</item>
    <item>233,GH</item>
    <item>350,GI</item>
    <item>30,GR</item>
    <item>299,GL</item>
    <item>502,GT</item>
    <item>224,GN</item>
    <item>245,GW</item>
    <item>592,GY</item>
    <item>509,HT</item>
    <item>504,HN</item>
    <item>852,HK</item>
    <item>36,HU</item>
    <item>91,IN</item>
    <item>62,ID</item>
    <item>98,IR</item>
    <item>964,IQ</item>
    <item>353,IE</item>
    <item>44,IM</item>
    <item>972,IL</item>
    <item>39,IT</item>
    <item>225,CI</item>
    <item>81,JP</item>
    <item>962,JO</item>
    <item>7,KZ</item>
    <item>254,KE</item>
    <item>686,KI</item>
    <item>965,KW</item>
    <item>996,KG</item>
    <item>856,LA</item>
    <item>371,LV</item>
    <item>961,LB</item>
    <item>266,LS</item>
    <item>231,LR</item>
    <item>218,LY</item>
    <item>423,LI</item>
    <item>370,LT</item>
    <item>352,LU</item>
    <item>853,MO</item>
    <item>389,MK</item>
    <item>261,MG</item>
    <item>265,MW</item>
    <item>60,MY</item>
    <item>960,MV</item>
    <item>223,ML</item>
    <item>356,MT</item>
    <item>692,MH</item>
    <item>222,MR</item>
    <item>230,MU</item>
    <item>262,YT</item>
    <item>52,MX</item>
    <item>691,FM</item>
    <item>373,MD</item>
    <item>377,MC</item>
    <item>976,MN</item>
    <item>382,ME</item>
    <item>212,MA</item>
    <item>258,MZ</item>
    <item>264,NA</item>
    <item>674,NR</item>
    <item>977,NP</item>
    <item>31,NL</item>
    <item>599,AN</item>
    <item>687,NC</item>
    <item>64,NZ</item>
    <item>505,NI</item>
    <item>227,NE</item>
    <item>234,NG</item>
    <item>683,NU</item>
    <item>850,KP</item>
    <item>47,NO</item>
    <item>968,OM</item>
    <item>92,PK</item>
    <item>680,PW</item>
    <item>507,PA</item>
    <item>675,PG</item>
    <item>595,PY</item>
    <item>51,PE</item>
    <item>63,PH</item>
    <item>870,PN</item>
    <item>48,PL</item>
    <item>351,PT</item>
    <item>1,PR</item>
    <item>974,QA</item>
    <item>40,RO</item>
    <item>7,RU</item>
    <item>250,RW</item>
    <item>590,BL</item>
    <item>685,WS</item>
    <item>378,SM</item>
    <item>239,ST</item>
    <item>966,SA</item>
    <item>221,SN</item>
    <item>381,RS</item>
    <item>248,SC</item>
    <item>232,SL</item>
    <item>65,SG</item>
    <item>421,SK</item>
    <item>386,SI</item>
    <item>677,SB</item>
    <item>252,SO</item>
    <item>27,ZA</item>
    <item>82,KR</item>
    <item>34,ES</item>
    <item>94,LK</item>
    <item>290,SH</item>
    <item>508,PM</item>
    <item>249,SD</item>
    <item>597,SR</item>
    <item>268,SZ</item>
    <item>46,SE</item>
    <item>41,CH</item>
    <item>963,SY</item>
    <item>886,TW</item>
    <item>992,TJ</item>
    <item>255,TZ</item>
    <item>66,TH</item>
    <item>228,TG</item>
    <item>690,TK</item>
    <item>676,TO</item>
    <item>216,TN</item>
    <item>90,TR</item>
    <item>993,TM</item>
    <item>688,TV</item>
    <item>971,AE</item>
    <item>256,UG</item>
    <item>44,GB</item>
    <item>380,UA</item>
    <item>598,UY</item>
    <item>1,US</item>
    <item>998,UZ</item>
    <item>678,VU</item>
    <item>39,VA</item>
    <item>58,VE</item>
    <item>84,VN</item>
    <item>681,WF</item>
    <item>967,YE</item>
    <item>260,ZM</item>
    <item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

And Then ...

```
public static String getCountryDialCode(){
    String contryId = null;
    String contryDialCode = null;

    TelephonyManager telephonyMngr = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    contryId = telephonyMngr.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    String[] arrContryCode=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DialingCountryCode);
    for(int i=0; i<arrContryCode.length; i++){
        String[] arrDial = arrContryCode[i].split(",");
        if(arrDial[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())){
            contryDialCode = arrDial[0];
            break;  
        }
    }
    return contryDialCode;
}
```

**Update :**

If there is no SIM card inserted ...

```
public String getCountryCode() {
    String my_country_code_letters = getMyLocale().getCountry();
    String[] country_codes = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DialingCountryCode);
    String my_country_code_number = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < country_codes.length && i != (-1); i++) {
        String[] split_code = country_codes[i].split(",");
        if (split_code[1].matches(my_country_code_letters)) {
            my_country_code_number = split_code[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return my_country_code_number;
}

public Locale getMyLocale() {
    Locale myLocale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        myLocale = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else {
        myLocale = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
    return myLocale;
}
```

Comment: `getSimCountryIso` is null if there is no SIM card inserted.

Comment: Works well but why the sdk check for android N?

Comment: There is a little difference between `get local`. For new versions we have `getLocals()` that return all available locals then select first one ( activated local ). But we can get activated local by `local` variable in Old versions @Micro

Comment: `getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale` still works on Android N though so I don't think that check is necessary unless you want multiple locales. I just want the first best one. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to get the country code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();

//without sim card
getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

Comment: try this: String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();